# Bit Manipulation Arithmetic and Order of Operations

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I am new to bit manipulation and just came across a situation where I was asked to find the inverse of XOR. It turned out to be XOR itself. This got me to thinking.

Given `x = a ^ b | ~c & d` if I gave you `x`, `a`, `b`, and `d` how would you solve for `c`?

If we go back to basic arithmetic, if I have something like `x = a - b + c * d` I know the order of operations and how to move each variable to the other side of the equation.  But I don't know how to do this with logical operations.

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Let's say `x = a | b` and I tell you that `x` and `a` are `1`. Can you solve for `b`?

Comment: Well I suppose `b` can either be a 0 or a 1.

Comment: Right. So what's the desired result format for "solve for c"? A set of all possible values? It might even be infinite, for example for `0 = 0 & b`, where `b` can be *any* int.

Comment: Okay, I see. I think it was a mistake to think of the operations in the same way as regular +,-,*,/ operators. Thanks

Comment: Well, not really. With multiplication there is already a similar problem: `x = a * b`, given `x` and `a`, there may not be a single unambiguous solution for `b`. Namely when `a = 0`. The same thing happens for bitwise AND (which quite closely relates to multiplication actually) and OR, but on a bit-by-bit level (so you may be able to solve some bits but not others).

Answer (score 0):

One way is to convert everything to using & ^ as operations only, along with a bit-vector of all ones (~0 in code). Write 1 as a bit-vector of all ones, and 0 as a bit-vector of all zeros. (Or think about single bits.)

Here's a quick translation method. Interpret bits 1 and 0 NOT as true and false, but as odd and even respectively, as in odd and even numbers. Then `exclusive or` is what happens to odd/even when you add integers: for example odd + odd = even corresponds to 1^1=0. Similarly `and` is what happens to odd/even when you multiply integers. So these operations inherit all the usual algebraic laws from the integers!

So write x+y for x^y and write xy for x&y to remind yourself of this. What happens when odd/even numbers are negated, i.e. x goes to -x? Odd remains odd and even remains even. So addition and subtraction are the same operation, as you discovered.

Now here's a translation table. (The last two can be checked using truth tables.)

`x^y` becomes `x+y`

`x&y` becomes `xy`

`x|y` becomes `x+y+xy`

`~x`  becomes `1+x`

Let's apply it to your equation.

```
x = a ^ b | ~c & d
  = (a ^ b) | ( (~c)& d )
  = (a + b) | ( (1+c)d )
  = (a + b) + (1+c)d + (a + b)(1 + c)d
```

Now suppose I say `(x,a,b,d) = (1,1,1,1)`, what is c ?

```
1 = (1 + 1) + (1 + c)1 + (1 + 1)(1 + c)1
  = 1 - 1 + 1 + c + (1 - 1)(1 + c)
  = 1 + c
So subtracting 1, which is the same as adding 1, gives,
0 = c.
```

Now lets do what algebra we can in general to find c.

```
x = (a + b) + (1+c)d + (a + b)(1 + c)d
  = (a + b) + d + cd + (a + b)d + (a + b)cd
  = (a + b)(1 + d) + d + d(1 + a + b)c
So, adding the parts without c to both sides
(d(1 + a + b))c = x + d + (a + b)(1 + d)
```

If the multiplier of c on the left evaluates to 0 with some assignment, then c can be anything, provided the right hand side is zero. If the right hand side is not zero under that assignment, then there is no solution.

If the multiplier of c on the left evaluates to 1, then the right hand side is a formula for the value of c, so there is exactly one solution.

When are there two or zero solutions for c? When the left hand multiplier is zero.

```
d(1 + a + b) = 0
```

and this occurs when `d=0` or `(1 + a + b)=0`. This last equation is equivalent to `a = 1+b` and since `1+b = ~b` the solutions are where a≠b. When does this lead to two solutions? When the right hand side is zero.

```
x + d + (a + b)(1 + d) = 0 when d=0 or a = 1 + b
In the first case this evaluates to
x + a + b = 0 which is satisfied when two of x,a,b are 1.
In the second case this is
x + 1 = 0 which means x = 1
```

So there are two solutions when

```
1. d=0 and ( two of x,a,b are 1 )
or
2. a≠b and x=1
```

In a similar way when there is one solution and when there are no solutions can characterized. It's the ideas that matter here, not the exact details.

Just as elsewhere in algebra, some situations will prove more tractable than others. Resorting to the brute force of truth tables makes every situation exponentially intractable and frequently unintelligible, and when there are potentially simple things they can be made hard to discover.

Doing algebra with & | ~ (boolean algebra) is much harder because canceling things out is difficult. Apart from cancelations when constants appear in expressions, cancellation only occurs using the absorption laws, `a&(a|b)=a` and `a|(a&b)=a`, which are quite complex patterns to steer expressions towards using the other rules of boolean algebra.